# Error when using SDK while offline: calculateRoute returns GRAPH_DISCONNECTED

Tags: here-api

After updating HERE SDK to version **3.12** we started getting a GRAPH_DISCONNECTED error when calling `calculateRoute` method of `CoreRouter` class (Wifi and mobile data turned off).

**Update**

This is how we are creating and using `CoreRouter`:

```
val routeOptions = RouteOptions().apply {
              transportMode = TransportMode.SCOOTER
              routeType = RouteOptions.Type.FASTEST
              routeCount = 1
            }

val routePlan = RoutePlan()
routePlan.routeOptions = routeOptions

val fromGeoCoordinate = GeoCoordinate(from.latitude, from.longitude)
val destinationGeoCoordinate = GeoCoordinate(destination.latitude, destination.longitude)
routePlan.addWaypoint(RouteWaypoint(fromGeoCoordinate))
routePlan.addWaypoint(RouteWaypoint(destinationGeoCoordinate))

val coreRouter = CoreRouter()
coreRouter.connectivity = CoreRouter.Connectivity.DEFAULT
coreRouter.calculateRoute(
    routePlan,
    object : Router.Listener<List<RouteResult>, RoutingError> {
        override fun onCalculateRouteFinished(routes: List<RouteResult>?, error: RoutingError?){
            Log.d(TAG, "onCalculateRouteFinished")
        }

        override fun onProgress(p0: Int) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onProgress")
        }
    })
```

Android version: 8.1.0

Currently, we are using version **3.9.0** which works fine in the same scenario.

Is there something else we need to do on our side to get it working with the new version?

Comment: Hi Guilherme, could you please post a bit of code (e.g from the instantiation of the CoreRouter and the calculateRoute function) to help us reproduce the error you are getting. Thank you.

Comment: Done! Updated my question with a sample code. Thanks!

Comment: The problem you are facing is more related to this: 'If a Connectivity.OFFLINE route calculation request fails due to not enough cached data, HERE SDK returns RoutingError.GRAPH_DISCONNECTED error code.'  Our team is looking into it why this happens only with version 3.12 and will get back to you soon.

Comment: To create route in offline mode in 3.12 version you have to preload map data using either MapLoader or MapDataPrefetcher, did you do that?

Comment: Yes, we preloaded map data using `MapLoader`. Also, I noticed that it works if I replace `RouteOptions.TransportMode.SCOOTER` with `RouteOptions.TransportMode.CAR`.

Comment: Could you provide geo coordinates for waypoints?

Answer (score 0):

In our latest release (3.16), you have to follow these steps to download and preload maps for offline use:

> Map Package Download
> The second method of getting offline maps capabilities is enabled through the use of MapLoader and its associated objects. The MapLoader class provides a set of APIs that allow manipulation of the map data stored on the device. Operations include:

> getMapPackages() - to retrieve the map data state on the device

> installMapPackages(List packageIdList) - to download and install new country or region data

> checkForMapDataUpdate() - to check whether a new map data version is available

> performMapDataUpdate() - to perform a map data version update if available

The complete documentation with snippets are at:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.16/dev_guide/topics/routing-offline.html